# Realtek HD audio broken?

Tags: audio, realtek-hd-audio

I came here because my Realtek audio won't allow me to use my headphones and my speakers.

I have two audio devices, my speakers and my headphones. My USB dongle for my headphones broke and I had to get a female to male 3.5mm jack to replace the dongle. Now I have two 3.5mm jacks plugged into two ports and Realtek HD audio only recognises it as one device and doesn't allow me to split the audio. My front audio panels don't work for whatever reason. (I've plugged them into the right ports, I believe they are broken. Any help would be appreciated. My drivers are up to date as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use an audio splitter [image: splitter] .

What you try to do is not good for the audio card.

Comment: How is it bad for the card?

Comment: How is it bad for the card? Also how will the splitter help me if it will still only be recognized as one device?

Comment: It will not be relevant how it is recognized since with only one volume control (like the headsets volume) you will be able to adjust both outputs (when you increase headset volume, speakers volume will automatically decrease and vice-versa). Or do you want to do something totally different and I miss-understood ?